# Is it possible to make a web from just like a excelsheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

We have a situation that need to user web form just like an ExcelSheet, Is it possible, Can any one suggest me how to make them.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. That's exactly what Google Docs Spreadsheet or Office 365 do. You need to use a lot of JavaScript to make user experience similar to a Excel Spreadsheet. I would start by looking at some open source projects that already do this. Like [TrimSpreadsheet](http://code.google.com/p/trimpath/wiki/TrimSpreadsheet).

Comment: @Cruz Thanks Cruz any simple example with you please

Answer (score 3):

very good plugin

http://visop-dev.com/Project+jQuery.sheet